# background color not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to coding, can anyone help me a solution for button4 for not working ?

```
document.getElementById=("button4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "blue";
});
```

Comment: plz provide a code snippet with you html and javascript

Comment: Please click F12 and fix the errors you see in the console

Comment: hint: what is `document.getElementById("box").style.background` minus `color`

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax,

```
document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "blue";
```

should be replaced with

```
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

AND

```
document.getElementById=("button4").addEventListener
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener
```

Final updated code would be

```
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```